# cmd+C, cmd+V для NSTextField и NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, gui, macos, cocoa

В проекте на objective-c несколько форм с различными текстовыми полями - NSTextField и NSTextView. В этих компонентах не работает сочетания клавиш для копирования текста в буфер обмена и вставки из него. У этих компонентов есть своё контекстное меню, через него копирование и вставка работают. Но нужно иметь возможность работать с текстом простым сочетанием клавиш, без меню.

Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: Можете дать минимальный пример проекта где эта проблема?

Comment: Создал новый cocoa-проект - формой и меню в комплекте. Разместил на форме NSTextField. Копи-паст в нём работает через меню формы. То есть, если убрать пункты из меню формы, то сочетания клавиш перестают работать в NSTextField. В своём проекте так и решил проблему - добавил пункты в основное меню, привязал к ним сочетания клавиш. Для меня такой подход не привычен. Возможно, что для cocoa проектов это норма.

Answer (score 1):

Для Cocoa-проектов это ожидаемое поведение и встречается во всех программах для macOS. Менять его не нужно, так что проблемы как таковой нет.